# Starting Django with docker unexpected character

Tags: python, sql, django, linux, macos

I'm trying to start up this Project on my Mac https://github.com/realsuayip/django-sozluk
It works on my Windows machine, but I got this Error on my Mac:

> unexpected character "." in variable name near "127.0.0.1 192.168.2.253\nDJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=djdict.settings_prod\n\n\nSQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql\nSQL_PORT=5432\nDATABASE=postgres\nSQL_HOST=db\n\nSQL_DATABASE=db_dictionary\nSQL_USER=db_dictionary_user\nSQL_PASSWORD=db_dictionary_password\n\n\nEMAIL_HOST=eh\nEMAIL_PORT=587\nEMAIL_HOST_USER=eh_usr\nEMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=pw"
> furkan@MacBook-Air-von-Furkan gs %

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Sorry about the answer - I don't yet have the rep to comment)*

Just want to add a note on to the answer by D.Mo - I had the same error this morning, and adding quotes around the values in my `.env` file did seem to resolve the issue.

Though I then noticed that in the [documentation for these env files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/#syntax-rules), Docker mentions

> There is no special handling of quotation marks. This means that they are part of the VAL.

Just wanted to point that out in case anyone ran into issues with this.

I will likely just keep this change locally until others in my team experience the same problem - unless someone can confirm that the ENV values should now have `""`s around them.

FWIW I could not find a way to disable Docker Compose V2 (I'm on Arch, Docker v20.10.9) - `docker-compose disable-v2` isn't a valid command for me (see [here](https://githubmemory.com/repo/docker/compose-cli/issues/1885) for what I assume is the (imo silly) reason).

---

*Edit - I ended up reverting to a previous version of `docker-compose` as the constant workarounds I had to implement weren't fun.
I did so after seeing [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1995468#p1995468) - I ended up looking around `yay -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/docker-compose-` and tab-complete gave me a list of cached versions. I went with `1.29.2-1` and things have been working perfectly again since then. Will just have to see what happens in future updates etc.*

Answer (score 18):

Turning off the "Use Docker Compose V2" flag in the settings did it for me.

Comment: Thanks!  I guess this got turned on after an update... totally saved me.

Comment: Same here  (using docker on macos)

Comment: Awesome. I noticed docker teams keep pushing updates that break many times

Comment: This fixed my issue too! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with a docker container. It probably appears after a system update under my linux. I can't say anything about the reason, but try following:

Quote the variable values in file ".env" of the Project, such as:

```
DEBUG=0
SECRET_KEY=foo
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS="localhost 127.0.0.1 192.168.2.253"
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="djdict.settings_prod"


SQL_ENGINE="django.db.backends.postgresql"

# ...
```

And try again

Answer (score 3):

Look at the "Use Docker Compose V2" option.
It seems it's ON now

Answer (score 2):

I changed Encoding of my `.env` file to `UTF-8`.
Earlier it was `UTF-8-BOM` and that caused the problem.

Comment: 10x, only this solution fixed it for me :)

Answer (score 1):

For latest mac M1. Use the UI to disable

> Use Docker Compose V2

or in terminal
`docker-compose disable-v2`

Answer (score 0):

For me running
`docker-compose disable-v2`
fixed the issue